# django templates - string concatenation to variable name

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to use a variable in a django template and this variable should be concatenated from 2 strings. Here's an example:

I'd like to do:

```
{% for item in ObjSearch %} ...
```

but the **ObjSearch** variable should be concatenated from the **Obj** string and from the **field** variable.

To get the string it works like this:

```
{{ "Obj"|add:field }}
```

but unfortunately it's not working like this:

```
{% for item in "Obj"|add:field %}
```

.

How can I achieve this?

-----Clarification with better example-----

From the views I receive the Objsearch variable which is a list (actually a queryset, but it does not matter).

I can't use Objsearch directly, the search part should come from a variable, so:

**"Obj"** is a string
**field** is a variable, and its value is "search"

Concatenating the "Obj" string and field variable I'll get the required Objsearch, but as a string, but i'd like to iterate over the Objsearch value. I'd need something like eval in python.

Comment: please clarify what is field and Obj and what are you trying to achieve show us https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I edited the original question with a better example. I hope it's clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong place to fix this. Fix it in your view, not your template. Just fill a know variable with the things you need to be in it.

Comment: It'd be good, but it's not possible at the moment. I can't change anything in the views file.

Comment: logic is not something you should fill templates with, this does look like complication without reason, how much of these different fields you have?

Comment: At the moment i've only one, but i'll have 3 more later.

Comment: Actually i need the for cycle' s html generated. It'd be a solution to do it from templatetags, however the only one problem there is the import. I can't import the Objsearch model as it's in a different pypi application.

Comment: Yeah, this is very contrived. Why does pypi factor into imports? I think you're making some assumptions that make you discard simpler solutions.

Comment: It doesn't, i just wanted to highlight that the different application means a different pypi app, and not a different django app, this is why I can't make the import working from the templatetags .

Comment: And yet, there is no difference. You can import a python module in your view, whether it's a Django app or not.

Comment: Not in this case. I've the u_s_e application, which import the other application called u_t_i_l_s . I need this "trick" in the u_t_i_l_s application, and there I've no chance to know the name of the imported model. Also u_t_i_l_s can be used by many application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a custom template tag.

First create a folder called yourapp/templatetags (remember to add a **init**.py file in the folder).
Then create a file called app_filters.py in the new folder (the name could be whatever you want). In the file add:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='array_to_string')
def array_to_string(array):
    return ''.join(array)
```

you can now use this method in your template like this:

```
{% load app_filters %}

{{array|array_to_string}}
```

Comment: I think it'll still only result a String, but i need the variable with the same name.

Comment: okay now I see what you're trying to do. I would still go with the template tag approach and do the logic in the app_filters.py